# Can `this` be changed in a mutable lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, this

Everyone knows that `this` object pointer in C++ cannot be changed in its methods. But what comes to mutable lambdas, where `this` is captured, some current compilers give such possibility. Consider this code:

```
struct A {
    void foo() {
        //this = nullptr; //error everywhere

        (void) [p = this]() mutable { 
            p = nullptr; //#1: ok everywhere
            (void)p;
        };

        (void) [this]() mutable { 
            this = nullptr; //#2: ok in MSVC only
        };
    }
};
```

In the first lambda `this` is captured and given a new name `p`. Here all compilers permit to change the value of `p`. In the second lambda `this` is captured by its own name, and only MSVC allows the programmer to change its value. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/x5P81TT4r

I believe MSVC behaves incorrectly in the second case (though it looks like a nice language extension). Could anyone find the right wording from the standard (the search is not easy since the word `this` is mentioned there 2800+ times)?

Comment: To clarify what's happening here: In the first case, `this` is captured by copy so changing it does not change the original pointer. This should always be allowed. In the second case, `this` is captured by reference because `[this]` is a special case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Init-captures of `this`

> ```
> (void) [p = this]() mutable { 
>     p = nullptr; //#1: ok everywhere
>     (void)p;
> };
> ```

This uses init-capture to capture the `this` pointer *by value*, as per [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6), meanings it's a copy of the `this` pointer. In contexts where `this` is `const`-qualified, the copy can naturally not be used to changed `this` (even if the lambda is mutable; compare with 'point to const'), but *as* the lambda is mutable, the pointer (copy) can be used to point to something different, e.g. `nullptr`.

```
struct S {
    void f() const {
        (void) [p = this]() mutable { 
            p->value++;   // ill-formed: 'this' is pointer to const, meaning
                          //             'p' is pointer to const.
            p = nullptr;  // OK: 'p' is not const pointer
            (void)p;
        };
    }
    
    void f() {
        (void) [p = this]() mutable { 
            p->value++;   // OK: 'this' is pointer to non-const, meaning
                          //     'p' is pointer to non-const.
            p = nullptr;  // OK: 'p' is not const pointer
            (void)p;
        };
    }
    int value{};
};
```

---

#### Simple-captures of `this`:

> ```
> (void) [this]() mutable { 
>     this = nullptr; //#2: ok in MSVC only
> };
> ```

As per [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture), ignoring the case of *capture-default*:s:

- A *capture-list* contains a *capture*
- A *capture* is either a *simple-capture* or an *init-capture*; we ignore the latter case as it was covered above
- A *simply-capture* has one of the following forms:

  - *identifier* ...<sub>opt</sub>
  - `&`*identifier* ...<sub>opt</sub>
  - `this`
  - `*this`

As per [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10) [**emphasis** mine]:

> An entity is captured by copy if
>
> - (10.1) it is implicitly captured, the capture-default is `=`, and the captured entity is not `*this`, or
> - (10.2) it is explicitly captured with a capture that is **not of the form `this`**, `&` *identifier*, or `&` *identifier initializer*.

Only the *simple-capture* form `*this` allows explicitly capturing the `*this` object by copy. The simple capture `this`, however, captures the `*this` object<sup>(+)</sup> by reference, as per [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#12):

<sup>(+) The *simple-capture*:s `this` and `*this` both denote the local entity `*this`, as per [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.capture#4).</sup>

> **An entity is captured by reference if it is** implicitly or
> **explicitly captured but not captured by copy**. It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the
> closure type for entities captured by reference. [...]

Thus:

```
struct S {
    void f() const {
        (void) [this]() mutable { 
            // '*this' explicitly-captured by-reference
            this->value++;   // ill-formed: 'this' is pointer to const
            this = nullptr;  // #2 ill-formed: 'this' is not a modifyable lvalue
        };
    }
    
    void f() {
        (void) [this]() mutable { 
            // '*this' explicitly-captured by-reference
            this->value++;   // OK: 'this' is pointer to non-const
            this = nullptr;  // #2 ill-formed: 'this' is not a modifyable lvalue
        };
    }
    int value{};
};
```

As per [[class.this]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.this#1), `this` is not a modifyable lvalue, which is why `#2` is ill-formed:

> In the body of a non-static ([class.mfct]) member function, the keyword `this` **is a prvalue** whose value is a pointer to the object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a member function whose type has a cv-qualifier-seq cv and whose class is `X` is “pointer to cv X”. [...]

Which, as per [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#12), applies also to when `this` is used in lambdas:

> The lambda-expression's compound-statement yields the function-body ([dcl.fct.def]) of the function call operator, but **for purposes of** name lookup, **determining the type** and value **of `this`** and transforming id-expressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) ([class.mfct.non-static]), **the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.**

MSVC is this incorrect to accept your snippet (accepts-invalid).

And indeed, in the following example ([demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h358aqMhE)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct S;

void g(S *& )  { std::cout << "lvalue pointer to S"; }
void g(S *&& ) { std::cout << "rvalue pointer to S"; }

struct S {
  void f() {
    auto l = [this]() { g(this); };
    l();
  }
};

int main() {
  S s{};
  s.f();
}
```

We expect the second `g` overload to be a better match, as `this` is a prvalue. However, whilst GCC and Clang behaves as expected:

```
// GCC & Clang: rvalue pointer to S
```

MSVC fails to even compile the program:

```
// MSVC: error, no viable overload; arg list is '(S *const )'
```

Which is in violation of [class.this]/1, as:

> [...] The type of `this` in a member function whose type has a cv-qualifier-seq cv and whose class is `X` **is “pointer to cv X”** [...]

... and not "const pointer to cv X" (constness on a prvalue would be weird, to begin with).

Comment: You wrote "...which is why #1 is ill-formed", but you meant "#2 is ill-formed", haven't you?

Comment: @dfrib Ah, got it. :-)

Comment: I would nit that `[this]` does exactly what you'd expect: it captures `this` "by-copy"... except `this` is just a pointer to the current method's receiver so that's like capturing that object by reference. Hence using `[*this]` to actually copy the object.

Comment: @HTNW I re-write my answer some. Somewhat confusingly, I actually think `[this]` captures the `this` pointer _by reference_, as per [expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10 and /12. Not that I would think it would make any difference as to how the this pointer itself is captured (by value of reference), as `this` is always a prvalue (which should apply also for when it is used in the function call operator of the closure type), and thus the semantics of an explicit `[this]` capture is indeed what you'd expect.

Comment: The simple-capture `this` does not capture the pointer by reference. [\[expr.prim.lambda.capture\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.prim.lambda.capture#4): "The *simple-capture*s `this` and `* this` denote the local entity `*this`." It's `*this` that is captured by reference or copy, respectively, not the pointer.

Comment: @bogdan You're right, thanks (I also wrongly referenced /7.2 for how `this` also denotes the local object `*this`, but /4 is indeed the on-target reference).

Comment: `[class.this]/1` *cannot* apply inside the lambda, because it would make `[*this](){ std::cout << this; }` refer to the original object, when we know it actually does rather refer to the capture-by-copy.

Comment: @BenVoigt [\[expr.prim.lambda.closure\]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.lambda.closure#12) implies that [class.this]/1 applies, "but for purposes of [...] determining the type and value of `this`". Even with a `[*this]` value capture, both GCC and Clang consistently respects [class.this]/1 w.r.t. `this` being a prvalue. Its constness depends on the mutability of the lambda for value-captured `[*this]`, and on the const-qualifier of the member in which the lambda was defined for reference-captured `[this]`; [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KNZVlcYdmEeDAv5T).

Comment: @dfrib: Yes, with that restriction "for purposes of determining the type and value" it makes sense again.  I think the answer would be clearer if that closure/12 were quoted.

Comment: @BenVoigt I updated with a reference to [...closure]/12.

Comment: FWIW, we seem to be treating closure/12 as if it said "value category" not "value".